# ActiveStorage::Blob: How to make sure that `analyzed` metadata always has "width"/"height" attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rails-activestorage

#### Steps to reproduce

Create a model with an Active Storage (S3) image attachment (a .png in my case). Using the default `active_storage_analysis`

#### Expected behavior

Since all I did was call the `analyze` method (which I assume is what's being called the first time around when an attachment is made), I expect it to originally have the width/height attributes.

#### Actual behavior

The Blob metadata is missing its width/height attributes:

```
#<ActiveStorage::Blob:0x00007fb934129130
 id: "d6d6922a-646f-446f-8656-b1301ca5ba59",
 key: "dm46dnva9crgu9k1r9y4bwmhz3oi",
 filename: "Cheddah_icon-60@3x.png",
 content_type: "image/png",
 metadata: {"identified"=>true, "analyzed"=>true},
 byte_size: 3559,
 checksum: "x+EHSQeB6l3Kvb+8SCMzxg==",
 created_at: Mon, 03 Jun 2019 14:56:13 UTC +00:00>
```

I then manually analyze the Blob by invoking the `analyze` method on it. It now has the width/height:

```
#<ActiveStorage::Blob:0x00007fb934129130
 id: "d6d6922a-646f-446f-8656-b1301ca5ba59",
 key: "dm46dnva9crgu9k1r9y4bwmhz3oi",
 filename: "Cheddah_icon-60@3x.png",
 content_type: "image/png",
 metadata: {"identified"=>true, "analyzed"=>true, "width"=>180, "height"=>180},
 byte_size: 3559,
 checksum: "x+EHSQeB6l3Kvb+8SCMzxg==",
 created_at: Mon, 03 Jun 2019 14:56:13 UTC +00:00>
```

#### System configuration

**Rails version**: 6.0.0.rc1

**Ruby version**: 2.6.2p47 (2019-03-13 revision 67232)

#### Extra info

- I'm using Sidekiq `v5.2.7`
- (not sure if relevant) my Variant Processor is VIPS:

```
image_processing (1.9.0)
      mini_magick (>= 4.9.3, < 5)
      ruby-vips (>= 2.0.13, < 3)
```

I'm aware that I can just create background jobs to do this every time the model is saved, but according to all the documentation I've been able to find, I shouldn't need to do this manually right?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 6.0.3.6, in the model, near the top

`after_commit :analyze_metadata_now`

```
def analyze_metadata_now
  image.analyze if image.attached?
end
```

Works for me. I also put in a check on the show page to remind me of the problem. The id is for bold and red.

```
<% if @doc.image.analyzed? %>
  <!-- had a message here while debugging -->
<% else %>
  <p id="error_explanation"><strong>Edit and resave because doc.image.metadata not created.</strong></p> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question this is expected behaviour. By default the image won't be analysed until the first request for it happens. `AnalyzeJob` happens asynchronously. So the background job you mention might not be a bad idea.

As for using the dimensions as attributes when they aren't always available, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67228171/312681) worked for me. This is specific to Active Storage attachment *variants* but should still apply:

```rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def image_tag_with_dimensions(variant, opts = {})
    if variant.processed?
      metadata = variant.processed.send(:record).image.blob.metadata
      if metadata['width']
        opts[:width] = metadata['width']
        opts[:height] = metadata['height']
      end
    end
    image_tag variant, opts
  end
end

# usage: 
= image_tag_with_dimensions model.logo_image.variant(resize_to_fit: [300, 200])
```