# Get metadata of Active Storage variant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have an Active Storage image variant e.g.

```rb
<%= image_tag model.logo_image.variant(resize_to_fit: [300, 200]) %>
```

I'm trying to get the `width` and `height` values of this variant (since they are unknown) for use in the `width` and `height` HTML attributes.

I expected them to be here:

```rb
model.logo_image.variant(resize_to_fit: [300, 200]).processed.blob.metadata
```

But this gives me the metadata of the *original* file not the resized variant e.g.

```
{"identified"=>true, "width"=>800, "height"=>174, "analyzed"=>true}
```

How do I get the dimensions of an Active Storage variant?

Comment: It seems to be regarded as a feature by rails maintainers. See: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34263

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Rails 6.1, finally all Variations are stored in a new model/database table and each variation with a Blob. Try upgrading, if this feature is relevant for you.

Very deep into the object, you can find then the variation blob, and thus the metadata, though!

Try:

```rb
model.logo_image.
 variant(resize_to_fit: [300, 200]).
 processed.send(:record).image.blob.metadata
```

It does not work the first time though, when called first time, it has no width/height, because the AnalyzeJob will run asynchronously, and it will add the width/height "later", depending on your queue setup.

Maybe add a helper_method that creates the image with width, height if available:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def image_tag_for_attachment_with_dimensions(variant, opts = {})
    if variant.processed?
      metadata = variant.processed.send(:record).image.blob.metadata
      if metadata['width']
        opts[:width] = metadata['width']
        opts[:height] = metadata['height']
      end
    end
    image_tag variant, opts
  end
end

# usage: 
= image_tag_for_attachment_with_dimensions model.logo_image.variant(resize_to_fit: [300, 200])
```

Comment: @AlecRust no problem! Could you accept the answer then ;)?

Comment: Answer accepted  I've made a couple edits. I assume this metadata is only now available in Rails 6.1 due to variant being tracked in database, as I looked everywhere on 6.0 and it wasn't present.

Comment: The `variant.processed.send(:record).image.blob.metadata` chain can be shortened to `variant.processed.send(:record).image.metadata`, since I believe a lot of the public methods of `blob` is delegated in `image`.

Comment: This no longer works with 6.1.4, raising: `undefined method 'record' for #<ActiveStorage::Variant:0x0000000132f782c0>`

Comment: Careful, while this is good for image dimensions, this strategy will give the file size (using byte_size) of the blob, which is the original image not the variant.